# how to increase the photoshop sprite canvas width and height

Tags: css, photoshop, css-sprites

I am creating a sprite via photoshop and have run out of canvas width .However when i try to increase the canvas width all the positions of the icons in the css seem to go off . I am using the relative increase method .

How do i only increase the height without affecting the css positions of the current layers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this has nothing to do with programming (*SO is about programming issues*)

You need to click the top-left box from the anchor section of the `canvas size`, so that the expansion happens only on the right and bottom. This way the positioning of the current contents does not get altered..

[image]